# Cannot connect to a WCF service from Web application hosted in IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, ssl

I have the following problem. I have a machine that runs a WCF service. This service is configured like this:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <client />
  <services>
    <service name="AnchorWcfService.AnchorService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="AnchorService" contract="AnchorWcfService.IAnchorService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" />
      <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxDepth="128" maxArrayLength="5000000" />
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This service is set up to use HTTPS and I ahve added the necessary test certificates using the `netsh` command line tool. I have created the certificates in the following way:

First I ran this command on my machine to create the root certificate

```
makecert -n "CN=RootCATest" -r -sv RootCATest.pvk RootCATest.cer
```

Then i copied the cer file to both the machine hosting the wcf service and the web server, and imported it using mmc.

Then on the machine hosting the wcf service i ran the additional command;

```
makecert -sk MyWcfService -iv RootCATest.pvk -n "CN=1.2.3.4" -ic RootCATest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is the IP of the machine hosting the wcf service.

Then I created the SSL certificate like this:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8080 certhash=<Thumbprint from the sertificate created in the last step> appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

From the web server machine I have successfully connected to this service using both `wcftestclient` and another .NET console application that I have created.

The problem is when I try to connect from the web application. I use the exact same code in the console application and the web application to consume the WCF service:

```
IAnchorService channel = null;
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
var channel = ChannelFactory<IAnchorService>.CreateChannel(binding, endpoint.Address);
var anchor = channel.GetAnchorDetails();
```

On the console application the last line successfully retrieves the anchor details from the wcf service, but on the web application I get the following exception:

`System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

I have also tested to remove the Security.Transport and set Security.None on both client and server (So using normal HTTP instead of HTTPS), and then everything works fine.

Also, if I put the service on the same machine as the web server, but still use HTTPS it also work.

So it only fails if the web server and wcf service are run on separate machines, and SSL is enabled.

I have tried everything I can come up with now. What do I have to do to get this to work on my web application?